# Php Db schema diagram creator

Tags: php, database, graphics, schema

Wondering if there is any php script out there which takes an sql db and diagramatically shows the entire thing (along with relationships)? Similar to what most mysql tools offer for desktop.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you [Entity-Relationship Diagram building software](http://www.trap17.com/index.php/freeware-entity-relationship-diagram-software_t4351.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look for FabForce DbDesigner.
http://fabforce.net/dbdesigner4/